# 毎ｎ番目の数字をリストから消したい

Tags: haskell

今Haskellを使ってタイトルでも書いたように毎ｎ番目の数字をリストから消すコードを書いているのですがどうもうまくいきません。

例）

```
dropevery [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 3
[0,1,3,4,6,7,9]
```

*2, 5, 8 と毎3番目の数字がリストから落とされ残った数字が表示されるコードです。

いま色々試しているのですがなかなかうまくいきません。
以下のコードは色々試して、いろいろなサイト等をみて書いたものです。まだコーディングが必要な箇所もあるのですが、何を書いたらいいのか分からないです（？と記入した箇所）

どなたか解決案がある方がいらしたら、答えていただけると幸いです。また訂正箇所もあったら教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

現在のコード

```
dropevery :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
dropevery [] _ = []
dropevery xs n = go 0 xs
    where go _ [] = []
          go i (y:ys) | i == n = 0（？）
                      | otherwise = ？
                                                                    
main = putStrLn (show (dropevery)[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

こちらでいかがでしょうか:

```hs
dropevery :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
dropevery xs n = go xs
 where
  go xs' =
    let (xsNotDropped, xsLeft) = splitAt (n - 1) xs'
     in
      case xsLeft of
          [] -> xsNotDropped
          (_ : xsAfterN) ->
            xsNotDropped ++ go xsAfterN


main = putStrLn (show (dropevery [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 3))
```

以下補足事項:

- もし勉強のために敢えてやっているのであれば恐縮ですが、こういうときは極力自分では再帰を書かずに、標準ライブラリーにある関数（上記の場合`splitAt`）を利用するのをお勧めします。
- 一般にHaskell製の関数は、他の多くのプログラミング言語と異なり、「主に処理する引数」を後ろに置くことが推奨されています。その方がカリー化と相性がいいためです（詳細が気になる場合は追加の質問を！）。なのでどちらかというと、`dropevery :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`という型にした方がいいかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

先頭のn要素を落した部分に対して当該の計算ができたら、それを先頭の(n-1)要素のリストにアペンドすればよい、という最後の一歩に気づけば、シンプルに以下のように考えることができます．

(1) 先頭から(n-1)個もぎとる
(2) 残りの先頭を捨てる
(3) その残りに dropEvery n を適用
(4) (1)と(3)を連結

```
dropEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropEvery _ [] = []
dropEvery n xs = take (n-1) xs ++ dropEvery n (drop n xs)
```

また、
(1)先頭から(n-1)個もぎ取る
(2)残りの先頭を捨てる
の部分を繰り返して、先に長さn-1以下のリストのリストを得て、これを concat で連結するという方法もあります.
「つきたて餅から少しずつ捻り取って丸めて黄粉をまぶして、黄粉もちをたくさんつくる」のような（個人の感想）この手法は、unfoldr :: (a -> Maybe (b, a)) -> a -> [b]（Data.Listモジュールにあります）という標準関数で抽象化されています．

```
dropEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropEvery n = concat . unfoldr f
    where
        f [] = Nothing
        f xs = Just (take (n-1) xs, drop n xs)
```